# How to make lightning:progressIndicator read only?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

We have a data entry form and we are using `lightning:progressIndicator` as a way to show their progress. However, we don't want the user to click-ahead nor do we want them to click back on the progress indicator.

Is there a way to make the `lightning:progressIndicator` ready only, so that the component doesn't interact with any user input?

There's nothing in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressIndicator) to support this, and I tried `disabled="true"` as well as `readonly="true"` but those did not do the trick.

Comment: it is my understandinig that the progress indicator will only change phases based on whatever criteria is set in your 'flow',  the progress indicator itself should not control wether the ui changes or not, but rather some other  factor, a button, a series of completed steps, etc, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Please Move your **`lightning:progressIndicator`**  inside div tag as below,

```html
<div class="slds-readonly-path">

    <lightning:progressIndicator aura:id="progress"
          currentStep="{!v.Stage}" type="path"/> 
       
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.THIS.slds-readonly-path{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```